# Extend urlpatterns dynamically

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have application app1. It has connected (through `INSTALLED_APPS`) app2; let's say that app2 is some kind of black-box for me. But I know that app2 in its urls has some number of i18n_patterns.
I need to include **all** urls from app2 to my app1. And include them at root position:

```
urlpatterns = ('',
    (r'', include("app1.urls")),
    (r'', include("app2.urls")),
)
```

because of i18n_patterns in app2.urls such `include` will raise
`ImproperlyConfigured('Using i18n_patterns in an included URLconf is not allowed.')`
 source code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/urls/__init__.py#L34)

Are there ways to append all the urlpatterns from `app2.urls` to my `urlpatterns` without knowing much about them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For instance, you can `from app2.urls import urlpatterns as urlpatterns2` and later in your `urls.py` at the end do this:

```
urlpatterns += urlpatterns2
# or maybe: 
# urlpatterns += urlpatterns2[1:] if you don't want to include the initial attribute
```

This behaves like a normal list concatenation and might work.

Note: This is a bit of hackery to overcome the include limitants. If there is a better way to do this I'll love to know.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sounds simple enough to be working solution :) I'll try it tomorrow and tell the result.